# Inserting document to MongoDB Atlas M0 (free tier) using Nodejs very slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have written a basic sign up form, which takes in 2 inputs from the user and inserts them in to a MongoDb Atlas database collection.

The backend is done using NodeJS and Express and connection to Mongo done with MongoClient.

I am only inserting single document

**My problem:**

It takes over a minute for the document to get inserted in database

ISSUE SEEMS TO BE DUE TO CONNECTION TO MONGO TAKING TOO LONG

**Frontend:**

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <section>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" required>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label for="new-password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
    </section>
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

**Backend:**

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(URI);

client.connect();
const db = client.db('testDB');
const col = db.collection('testCollection');

app.post('/signup', async function(req, res, next) {

  try {
    const newUser = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    }
    col.insertOne(newUser);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    res.redirect('/');
  }

});
```